# Can I create a regular expression that has some static text "X" followed by a recursive text?

Tags: python, regex, recursion

I'm using the `regex` module in Python3, and I want to be able to check a string to match that of a "zero or singley-templated" C++ datatype, such as `Foo`, `Foo<Bar>`, `Foo<Bar<Baz>>`, `Foo<Bar<Baz<Hello<World>>>>`, etc.

At the moment, I have `(<X(?R)?>)*`, where `X` is some text. This almost works for all of those examples given, it's just that they have to be surrounded by `<>` pairs themselves as well.

I'm looking for a way to be able to have some text out front of what's considered this recursive portion. Is this possible with regular expressions?

Comment: Regular expressions can't count (because they are not context free*), which is necessary to match matching parantheses. So no, you can't.

Comment: You can use more sophisticated tools like `ANTLR` for that. Although, if that it's the only thing you want, it shouldn't be so hard to do it with your own method.

Comment: Dang, that's a shame. Thanks @L3viathan! And ya that's the plan now @dcg, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`regex` does allow for recursive regular expressions (these expressions aren't strictly regular, which is why you're getting conflicting information), you just need to add a base case:

```
(?>\w+<(?R)>)|\w+
```

This matches with

```
regex.match(r"(?>\w+<(?R)>)|\w+", "Foo<Bar<Baz>>")
# <regex.Match object; span=(0, 13), match='Foo<Bar<Baz>>'>
```

Comment: Ah, the new `regex` module, nice. It's not possible with the builtin `re` module afaik.